# Can Calamity Janet play a Punch as Missed?

Tags: bang

*She can play BANG! cards as Missed! cards and vice versa*: can she use a Punch (or any other BANG card, e.g. Knife or Buffalo Rifle) as Missed?

Vice versa, can she use an Iron plate as a Bang?

If I take, for example, Jourdonnais, he can use his ability also when he's hit by something different from the card BANG!. I'd tend to think the same is true for Calamity Janet too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No she can not play a punch as a miss. BANG! are specific cards and those are the only one she can use as a miss. There are other cards that can be used to damage players but they are not considered a BANG!. One of the key parts of a BANG! is you can only play one of them a turn unless you got a card that says otherwise and a punch or other damage card can be played as many times as you want.

Comment: You're right. The point is the difference between "BANG!" and "BANG! cards"